# Switch statement that cycles through the cases one after another in iOS

Tags: ios

I would like the action to do case 0 the first time it is clicked, then case 1, then 2... etc.

How would I go about that?

Thanks!

```
- (IBAction) cycleAction{
switch (??????){
    case 0:
            [self choice1];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self choice2];
        break;
    case 2:
        [self choice3];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance variable that keeps track of the next action to perform.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    int _nextActionNumber;
}

- (IBAction) cycleAction {
    int actionNumber = _nextActionNumber++;
    if (_nextActionNumber == NumberOfActions)
        _nextActionNumber = 0;
    switch (actionNumber) {
        case 0:
            [self action0];
            break;
        case 1:
            // etc.
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't quite work. where do I declare _lastActionNumber and NumberOfActions?

Comment: I have changed `_lastActionNumber`; that was a typo.  You need to make `NumberOfActions` a constant that is the number of different actions.  You can declare it wherever you want, as long as it's before you use it.

Comment: got it working with this       int actionNumber = _nextActionNumber++;
        if (_nextActionNumber == 4)
            _nextActionNumber = 0;
        switch (actionNumber++) {

Comment: thanks, rob. seems to work better with switch (actionNumber++) for me. any reason I shouldn't use that? thanks a bunch.

Comment: Yeah, that was another mistake on my part.  It's fixed now.  How embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer, same as Rob Mayoff, just a little simpler.

At top of (.m) implementation:

```
@interface XYZMasterViewController ()
@property int count;

@end

@synthesize count;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{  
    count = 0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Somewhere in (.m) Implementation:

```
- (IBAction)doFunction:(id)sender
{

    switch (count) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"Count = %d",count);
            //[self action_1];
            count++;
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"Count = %d",count);
            //[self action_2];
            count++;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```